# Unable to deploy iPhone app on device

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode6, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am trying to deploy my app on iPhone 4 (running iOS 7.1) using Xcode 6. When I go to Window -> Devices, I can see my iPhone there but a yellow warning sign next to it. I cannot see any "Use For Development" button. Nor can I see the provisional profiles when I right click and select "Show provisional profiles"

Here is the picture if you want to see:

[image]

[image]

Although I have entered valid Provisional Profiles in Xcode as you can see:

[image]

**Updated:**

This is what I get when I try to run the project:

[image]

Any idea what is going wrong?

**Second update:**

I have pasted the log on pastebin.com because of its length. In case it helps here is the link:

http://pastebin.com/6bgBxtyx

Comment: Got the latest version of Xcode 6? One version of it said it didn't support iPhone 4 (I have that phone). Later, it started supporting it.

Comment: @Almo I tried it on Xcode Version 6.1.1 and Xcode-Beta Version 6.2. Didn't work on any of them. Same problem.

Comment: Try quitting XCode and rebooting the iPhone. Sounds dumb but it has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of All ,Make sure your device's UDID is added in the provisioning profile
And Project `deployment target` in `Build Settings` is set to 7.0 as your device is not iOS 8 supported, it won't work, then you'll be able to download the iOS 7 supported Simulators, once you have downloaded, You can test on Both Simulators and Real Devices.
Hope this works

Comment: Try a new Provisioning Profile

Comment: I created a new Provisioning Profile but its still not working. Check my updated question to see what I am getting when I try to run the project.

Comment: Make sure you quit Xcode and relaunch it. Also do a clean build, and then try to run on the device. Can you successfully run the app in the simulator running iOS 7?

Comment: Did you ran this application using  iOS 8 simulator ??
Because This is something related to conflicting Versions Between Xcode and iOS  Versions..
Download the iOS 7 simulator and run it. If it runs then it should also run on this iOS 7 version Device..

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem before, and it took me forever to fix it. Unfortunately, I don't really have enough information... so one question: is it listed as an "ineligible device"? If so, go to "Product" > "Destination" > "Your Device".

I've included a screenshot (instead of "iOS device", if you have your device plugged in, it should say the name of your device).[image]

**Note: you should also try unplugging and re-plugging your USB into your computer.**

**Note 2: Sorry if I misunderstood the question... it was a bit vague. :P**
I hope this helps!